# UE4 tips how to handle Minigolf Multiplayer

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

Heyo!

I'm doing a Minigolf multi-player game right now. What I couldn't figure out by now is how to set up the game logic of the actual game. So where to keep track of all players being in bounds, the scores or when everyone is in the hole to load the next hole. And how do that anyway? Do I keep different versions of the same map with different spawns and travel there after that  or can I move somehow spawns and everything else staying in the same level?

I'm sorry if this is confusing or there is not enough information to follow me there. Please aks when something is unclear!

Comment: There is never just one solution for a problem in software development. So whenever you wonder "Do I solve this problem this way or that way?" then the answer is usually "Whatever solution you feel is a better fit for the archtecture of *your* game".

Comment: What exactly does "player being in bounds" mean? What bounds does this refer to? Most minigolf simulations I have seen don't have actual players as entities in the physics simulation. They only simulate balls and "disembodied" putters.

Comment: I know there is never only one, I was just wondering which approach would be the best to follow. Because right now I can't really think of where to put the logic and what kind of logic I'm going to implement. Right now I'm thinking of having 9 of the same maps with different spawn point on each hole so I can travel to the next after one is complete. But in general it sounds really overpowered to have 9 copies of the same map just to travel and move Logik to another hole. What I mean by on bounds is that there is some collision cubes on the hole and whenever someone leaves that he gets respawnt

Comment: An I assume "someone" and "he" refers to the ball?